# Nexus 4 auto dialing extension does not work

Tags: calls, automation, phone-app, nexus-4, people-app

I used to own a T-Mobile Mytouch 4g before, which had the pause character before extension otherwise '*p*' on that handset and it was working fine.

Now, I own and use a Nexus 4 and I understood that the pause character on the Nexus 4 is '*,*' (*a comma*).

I replaced all the contact entries that had a '*p*' with '*,*' (*a comma*) in my contacts. And now it is not working, basically, what happens is when I make the call using that contact's number, the number gets called but the extension is not dialled automatically.

Anyone would know how to fix my issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I changed in the google voice settings to only use it for international calls, which fixed the problem. 
When dialing out using Google Voice, I can't get the auto extension feature to work, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I'm with Telus and had a v1 sim card. After cutting it into a micro sim everything seemed to work. except auto dial for extensions.

eg. 1-555-556-7899,,123

I replace the sim with a v3. Issue resolved. Sim card was to old strangely enough.